# IntelliJ IDEA 16 add maven dependencies to classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and using 2016.2 version. Previously I was using Eclipse. I am trying to set up a simple maven spring test project, however I can't figure out what is wrong.

*Note:* I know what the exception means, and I know the solution using Eclipse

*Note 2:* I tried on a clean Idea installation

As per my understanding, idea will include maven dependencies automatically (correct me if i'm wrong)

*edit 1:*  **Solution**

1. Project -> Right Click -> Add Framework Support -> Check Spring / Spring MVC
2. add `<packaging>war</packaging>`
3. Re-import maven dependencies

**What I tried to do**

1. Re-import maven dependencies
2. Close IntelliJ and remove all *.iml files and all .idea folders

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sample2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sample2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

sample2-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sa</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.17.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> As per my understanding, idea will include maven dependencies
>   automatically (correct me if i'm wrong)

Yes, if `Auto Import` is checked in when it prompts as and when you open the IntelliJ is clicked.

If not, please click on `Maven Projects` on the right side pane of the Intellij and click on button after `refresh` -> `Generate sources and auto import`. This triggers the process again.

[image: Maven-IntelliJ]

If the above doesn't work and still you have problem with IDE, go to `File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart` option. That prompts as below.

[image]

Click on `Invalidate and restart`, this will re-index all the dependencies to the workspace.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to solve other dependencies which had red underline.

Comment: apparently I forgot to add "<packaging>war</packaging>" to pom.xml file, and even after I added it did not import properly. Thanks.

Comment: Similar problem - Maven compile and code completion in IDE worked fine but Run or Build complained about non-existing packages in several projects. Tried many things, `File - Invalidate Cache/Restart` finally solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do the following to all poms in the project:

Right click on pom.xml and "Add as maven project".

Answer (score 1):

To force a reimport, open the maven projects tool window from the "view" menu (or the right side of the screen where it's docked by default) and press the left most icon (looks like a blue circle with arrows in it).
This should force IntelliJ to parse the pom from scratch and import any dependencies it's missing.
Often faster than a restart and clearing your caches if an automatic import doesn't quite work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->settings-->build,Execution,Deployment-->buildtools-->maven
maven home directory to your home directory.
If it does not work, in File->settings-->build,Execution,Deployment-->buildtools-->maven->importing tab,check import maven projects automatically.

Comment: The settings you mentioned are already set by default. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As per accepted answer, if someone forget to check Auto Import when prompted and maven build is not showing any Maven dependencies under External libraries, try this (for those who see in 2021).

> Right Click on the Project Folder

> Maven->Re-Import

[image]